# Getting invalid input error on procurve 2510 when setting up ip helper-address

Tags: hp, vlan, hp-procurve

I have 3 HP Procurve 2510G-48 and I want to setup a VLAN for public wifi (VLAN100). Originally I just had the default vlan1. I have computers communicating across switches on VLAN100 with static IP addresses just fine. The problem is getting DHCP from a server on VLAN1. When I go into a procurve to setup an ip helper-address I get the following result:

```
ProCurve Switch 2510G-48(vlan-100)# Ip helper-address 10.4.20.251 

Invalid input: helper-address
```

All documentation I have read says this command should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Layer2-only switch. No routing capabilities, hence the lack of the helper-address command set.

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont think the 2510G-48 supports the IP Helper-address command despite documentation I have read. I was able to setup IP Helper in my Sonicwall NSA 2400 and everything seems to be working now

Comment: That's normal - ip helper is only available on routing switches, which the 2510 isn't.